# Convergence of the integral(help with my appeal).

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I need a help with my appeal. My task was to find an expected value of some random variable $Y$, or to prove it doesn't exist.

All ended up to 
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y]=  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{ue^u}du \tag{1}
$$
And know I need to check it for convergence.

**Here is my solution:**

Firstly, the integrand is always positive.

I showed that
$$
\lim_\limits{u \to 1^-} \frac{\frac{1}{ue^u}}{\frac{1}{u}}=e^{-1}
$$
which is finite and positive. Hence, by a Limit Comparison Test the integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{ue^u}du \tag{2}
$$
diverges since the integral:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u}du 
$$
diverges. 
And then I said that the divergence of the integral $(2)$ implies the divergence of the integral $(1)$ and we're done.

**Feedback from examiners:**

*The divergence of the integral $(2)$ DOES NOT implies the divergence of the asked integral $(1)$.*

What? Why? Are they wrong? I believe they are! This is my argument:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{ue^u}du = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{ue^u}du + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{ue^u}du
$$

We have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{ue^u}du=\infty$$

All we should know about the integral $$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{ue^u}du>0$$ is that it is positive(does not depend convergent or divergent it is).
And then 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{ue^u}du=\infty + something>0=\infty$$

And that's it! Is this argument good enough?

Comment: I think you are right and they are wrong...but perhaps there's some good argument I haven't thought of...